# Including signals2 header gives compile error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

I have a project that compiles just fine, but I wanted to add some functionality using signals2.

When including boost/signals2/signal.hpp to one of my classes, I get these two errors:

> Error 10  error C2338: found >= Align d:\boost_1_53_0\boost\type_traits\type_with_alignment.hpp   206 1   TestProject
>
> Error 11  error C2338: found % Align == 0 d:\boost_1_53_0\boost\type_traits\type_with_alignment.hpp   207 1   TestProject

Removing the include, everything compiles just fine again. Does anybody know why I get this compile error? With the very limited error message, I am rather clueless as to why this happens.

I am using MSVC++ 2010

Update: Adding the include to TestProject.cpp (where my main-function is, and the class is instanciated) as well as including it in the class' header file solved the error. By removing the include from TestProject.cpp, the error comes back.

Comment: What is the compiler, platform? Do you add any signal-related code, or just including this header causes this error?

Comment: MSVC++ 2010. No signal-related code added, just included the header. I have also included boost/asio.hpp and boost/bind.hpp

Comment: post the contents of `TestProject.cpp` or a [minimally complete example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.